# Remove Plymouth Budgie Theme?

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth, budgie

A long time ago I was experimenting with desktop environments, and one of them was the Budgie desktop. I uninstalled it a while ago, and since I installed it, my plymouth theme turned gray instead of black and has the budgie logo whenever I log out or shut down (even after uninstalling the DE, that was clearly something that stuck around). It was just until today that I realized the package was called `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo` and there is also another one called `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-text`. I would like to remove those as I do not use the Budgie desktop anymore.

**First:**
Is it safe to remove these packages, and if I do, will it revert back to the original plymouth theme, or will my plymouth get messed up in some way?

**Second:** If I can remove the theme, what is the best way to do so? Just remove those packages? There are some other plymouth-related packages and I don't know what goes with what:

```
plymouth-label/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
plymouth-theme-spinner/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo/focal,focal,now 0.12.3 all [installed]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-text/focal,focal,now 0.12.3 all [installed]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed]
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
plymouth-themes/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed]
plymouth/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

How do I remove the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo` with the command `sudo apt remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo`. The plymouth theme will revert to your previous, which is still installed.

Comment: Thanks, my theme reverted to the original Ubuntu spinning wheel sucessfully.